# Dell Inspiron 15R N5110 keyboard not working

Tags: keyboard, dell-inspiron

keys are my Dell Inspiron 15R Laptop are not working. I have replaced hard drive of my laptop. when I installing keyboard its grip (that handled the cable) is broken and also I connect the cable wrong position. After that I reconnect it and some how the cable grip is fixed. Now sometimes some keys are working and sometimes it doesn't. What can I do now?

Answer (score 0):

if the keyboard isn't working right, it could be an issue with any number of things. unless you fancy getting your hands dirty, there really isn't a 'quick fix' available to you besides plugging in an external keyboard.

if it's a dell, you might apply for dell tech support - try looking on their website and quoting the service tag.

there are probably engineers who will look at it for you, but in my experience dell tech support isn't particularly cheap.